# How to add onChange function for all HTML form fields

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom, xhtml

My HTML Page has 10 Text Fields.

Currently no onChange EVENT is available for all ten fields.

```
<input type="text" name="text1" value="1">
<input type="text" name="text2" value="2">
<input type="text" name="text3" value="3">
<input type="text" name="text4" value="">
<input type="text" name="text5" value="">
<input type="text" name="text6" value="">...
```

Now, I want to add onChange Function in all fields whose field is of `input` type.

How do I add onChange or onBlur even in my JS section?

In onChange function, I will call ajax function which will validate whether the field has Hacking Keywords.

So my question is:

How do I add onChange function for all form fields. My field should dynamically be like below:

```
<input type="text" name="text1" value="1" onChange="javascript:fnName" onBlur="javascript:fnName" >
<input type="text" name="text2" value="2" onChange="javascript:fnName" onBlur="javascript:fnName" >
<input type="text" name="text3" value="3" onChange="javascript:fnName" onBlur="javascript:fnName" >
<input type="text" name="text4" value="" onChange="javascript:fnName" onBlur="javascript:fnName" >
<input type="text" name="text5" value="" onChange="javascript:fnName" onBlur="javascript:fnName" >
<input type="text" name="text6" value="" onChange="javascript:fnName" onBlur="javascript:fnName" >
<input type="text" name="text7" value="" onChange="javascript:fnName" onBlur="javascript:fnName" >
```

Comment: 1) The `on...` attributes should contain only valid Javascript, so `"fnName()"` or `"return fnName();"` or something, and 2) since this is tagged XHTML, refrain from using capitals in attribute names.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved with vanilla JavaScript as [**zvona**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/212878/zvona) suggests.

Here is a simple loop to mock an HTML5 placeholder. <<[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/TMR6U/)>>

```js
var prompt = 'Type something here';

var textFields = document.querySelectorAll('input[name^="text"]');
var index = 0;

for (index = 0; index < textFields.length; ++index) {
    var textField = textFields[index];
    textField.addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
    textField.addEventListener('focus', onFocusHandler);
    textField.addEventListener('blur', onBlurHandler);
    textField.value = prompt;
    console.log(textField);
}

function onChangeHandler() {
    // Do something...
}

function onFocusHandler() {
    if (this.value === prompt) {
        this.value = '';
    }
}

function onBlurHandler() {
    if (this.value === '') {
        this.value = prompt;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try to give change function to your form using

```
$('.form :input').change(function(e){
   $('#log').prepend('<p>Form changed ' + $(e.target).attr('id') + '</p>')
});
```

[Demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/kNx8p/227/)

[Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/kNx8p/228/)

Answer (score 1):

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("input"), function(input) {
  input.addEventListener("change", fnName, false);
  input.addEventListener("blur", fnName, false);
});
```

Comment: http://toddmotto.com/ditch-the-array-foreach-call-nodelist-hack/

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagname()` gets you an array of all input. Interate over them and addEventListener.

Or use jQuery's `$('input').on('change'...)`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
var inputList = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i=0;i<inputList.length;i++){
    inputList[i].onchange = function(){
        //function here
    }
    inputList[i].onblur = function(){
        //function here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `<input>`s are in a form, you can assign an onchange event handler to the form itself. It will trigger when any element changes, after the focus moves away from it.

Though you probably want an `input` event handler. For example, to enable a "Save" button when any input in a form has changed, you can do this:

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('input', event => {
  document.querySelector('form button').removeAttribute('disabled');
  document.querySelector('form button').textContent = 'Save';
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="number" min="0">
  <button type="submit" disabled>Input something...</button>
</form>
```