# localStorage conflicts with Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using `localStorage` to save values filled in HTML form after refreshing browser in following:

```
<form id="localStorageTest" method="post" action="">
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="stored" value="" />

            <label>Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="stored" value="" />

            <label>Message:</label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" class="stored"></textarea>

            <input type="submit" class="demo-button" value="Submit" />
        </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    function init() {
        if (localStorage["name"]) {
            $('#name').val(localStorage["name"]);
        }
        if (localStorage["email"]) {
            $('#email').val(localStorage["email"]);
        }
        if (localStorage["message"]) {
            $('#message').val(localStorage["message"]);
        }
    }
    init();
});

$('.stored').change(function () {
    localStorage[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
});

$('#localStorageTest').submit(function() {
    localStorage.clear();
});
</script>
```

Alone code above working correctly, but If I'm using Javascript function in `<head></head>` section It stop filling values.

This is Javascript function where I found conflict, If I'm removing It, `localStorage` working correctly.

```
$(function() {
    $("[type=date]").datepicker({
        monthNamesShort: $.datepicker.regional["en"].monthNames,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        yearRange: "-116:+10"
    });
});
$.fn.optionTest = function(opts) {
    var option = $.extend({}, $.fn.optionTest.defaults, opts);
    $(this).change(function() {
        option.holderObject = $(this);
        if (option.clearOnChange) {
            $(option.actionId).empty();
        }
        var val = $(this).val();
        if ($.fn.optionTest.isArray(val)) {
            $.fn.optionTest.parseArray(val, option);
        } else {
            var label = $(this).children("option:selected").eq(0).text();
            $.fn.optionTest.parseContent(val, option, label);
        }
        $('.' + option.removeLinkOptions.class).click(function(event) {
            $.fn.optionTest.removeRow(this, option);
            event.preventDefault();
        });

        $("[type=date]").datepicker({
            monthNamesShort: $.datepicker.regional["en"].monthNames,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            yearRange: "-116:+10",
        });
        return this;
    });
};
```

I found strange thing, even if I'm leaving only:

```
$.fn.optionTest = function(opts) {

};
```

Or only this (without `$.fn.optionTest`):

```
$(function() {
    $("[type=date]").datepicker({
        monthNamesShort: $.datepicker.regional["en"].monthNames,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        yearRange: "-116:+10"
    });
});
```

`localStorage` still not filling data. Why It happens? How can I solve It?

**UPDATE**

I've changed It like this, but still the same:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    function init() {
        if (localStorage["name"]) {
            $('#name').val(localStorage["name"]);
        }
        if (localStorage["email"]) {
            $('#email').val(localStorage["email"]);
        }
        if (localStorage["message"]) {
            $('#message').val(localStorage["message"]);
        }
    }
    init();

    $('.stored').change(function () {
        localStorage[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
    });

    $('#localStorageTest').submit(function() {
        localStorage.clear();
    });
});
</script>
```

I'm using this code below HTML form.

And as mentioned before If I'm removing below function from `<head></head>` It starts working...

```
$.fn.optionTest = function(opts) {
   .....
};
```

Comment: all DOM related jQuery stuff has to be inside `$(function(){` or `$(document).ready(function(){` , else it will not find the DOM elements when executed (see your first piece of code).

Comment: @Hacketo thank you for suggestion, but I can't achieve It correctly, could you show me how It should be done with this code?

Comment: @hacketo `Init` function is inside `$(document).ready(function () {`, but not working....

Comment: `$('.stored').change` isn't, and `$('#localStorageTest').submit` isn't

Comment: @Hacketo I've passed them inside `$(document).ready(function () {`, but still not working, updated my question with details.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem, but failed. Here is the code I tried: http://plnkr.co/edit/Dk7CniIPwhBeeMJdm1y3?p=preview

Comment: no need to create a wrapper for this function `init()` you can directly put this code in `ready` handler;

Comment: Impossible to debug without *full* source. For example: `(1)`: did you load the Datepicker library (when/where)? `(2)`: What is calling `optionTest()` when/where? `(3)`: Did you define your `optionTest.defaults`, `optionTest.isArray`, `optionTest.parseArray`, `optionTest.parseContent` and `optionTest.removeRow` (when and where)? I think `localStorage` is working as intended and that you have one or more bugs somewhere else.

Comment: @GitaarLAB thank you for your try to help, I'm discussing about It here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36421341/continue-html-form-filling-after-closing-and-re-opening-again in comments. I almost done, just looking for dynamic solution.

Comment: *that* question asks about saving drafts of a form (or form-content). *this* question then continues and states: I have draft-saving-code X (using localStorage) and that works *unless* I re-locate that code X to the head section, but when I then remove code Y and/or Z then code X also works in the head section. I'm saying that we can not debug the problem described in *this* (current) question without examining more (if not all) of the code that results in the 'unexpected behavior'.

Comment: @GitaarLAB you can check JSFiddle what I have for now: https://jsfiddle.net/r6gk8L86/14/ In another question guy suggessted me to use `onchange="save()"` and It looks like working. But for reality I have over 150 textbox fields, so in this case I need to create over 150 functions? I'm looking for way how could I achieve dynamically without repeating code n times. What I mean for now in provided fiddle code working only for `FirstName`, but how can I achieve that It worked for all fields in simplest way?

Comment: You have twice the `$("[type=date]").datepicker({...` listener, once inside the optionTest, once outside. It's surely not the problem talked here, but it could be another one.

Comment: Have you ever checked your developer console? I guess it is very likely that the function you mentioned cause error and therefore javascript after that line doesn't run.

Comment: You have already give us a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6gk8L86/14).  To focus on the question, can you give us a *not* working fiddle?  150 textbox is another question and is [easy to solve](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953582/).

Comment: @Sheepy could you help to use your provided solution with my code?

Comment: Voted to close because this question seeking debugging help ("*Why It happens? How can I solve It?*") does not include  the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem in the question itself (as pointed out by numerous experts).

Comment: @GitaarLAB what are you talking about? I've posted all I've tried and can't achieve It successfully, that's why I'm asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you place the working script above, in the head, you will need to move your .change and .submit functions inside the $(document).ready(function(){}) so that the elements exist before binding the event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r6gk8L86/15/

```js
setTimeout( load_all, 1000 ); // Delayed run so you can see it loads

/** Load stored values for all inputs */
function load_all () {
   try { // Check browser support
      localStorage.length;
      $( '.stored' ).each( load_one ).on( 'input', save );
   } catch ( err ) {
      $("#localStorageTest").prepend( '<p>Sorry, no Web Storage: "'+err+'"</p>' );
   }
}

/** Load stored value for an input */
function load_one () {
   this.value = localStorage.getItem( this.id ) || '';
}

/** Save value to store */
function save ( event ) {
   var element = event.target;
   if ( element.value )
      localStorage.setItem( element.id, element.value );
   else
      localStorage.removeItem( element.id );
}
```

```css
label { font-family: monospace; }
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<form id="localStorageTest" method="post" action="">
   This won't run on StackOverflow because its snippet is sandboxed. (no storage access)<br/>
   <!-- 20 text fields + 20 email fields + 1 textarea -->
   <label>Name :</label> <input name= "name00" id= "name00" class="stored" placeholder= "name00" />
   <label>Email:</label> <input name="email00" id="email00" class="stored" placeholder="email00" type="email" /><br/>
   <label>Name :</label> <input name= "name01" id= "name01" class="stored" placeholder= "name01" />
   <label>Email:</label> <input name="email01" id="email01" class="stored" placeholder="email01" type="email" /><br/>
   <label>Name :</label> <input name= "name02" id= "name02" class="stored" placeholder= "name02" />
   <label>Email:</label> <input name="email02" id="email02" class="stored" placeholder="email02" type="email" /><br/>
   <label>Name :</label> <input name= "name03" id= "name03" class="stored" placeholder= "name03" />
   <label>Email:</label> <input name="email03" id="email03" class="stored" placeholder="email03" type="email" /><br/>
   <label>Name :</label> <input name= "name04" id= "name04" class="stored" placeholder= "name04" />
   <label>Email:</label> <input name="email04" id="email04" class="stored" placeholder="email04" type="email" /><br/>
   <label>Name :</label> <input name= "name05" id= "name05" class="stored" placeholder= "name05" />
   <label>Email:</label> <input name="email05" id="email05" class="stored" placeholder="email05" type="email" /><br/>
   <label>Name :</label> <input name= "name06" id= "name06" class="stored" placeholder= "name06" />
   <label>Email:</label> <input name="email06" id="email06" class="stored" placeholder="email06" type="email" /><br/>
   <label>Name :</label> <input name= "name07" id= "name07" class="stored" placeholder= "name07" />
   <label>Email:</label> <input name="email07" id="email07" class="stored" placeholder="email07" type="email" /><br/>
   <label>Name :</label> <input name= "name08" id= "name08" class="stored" placeholder= "name08" />
   <label>Email:</label> <input name="email08" id="email08" class="stored" placeholder="email08" type="email" /><br/>
   <label>Name :</label> <input name= "name09" id= "name09" class="stored" placeholder= "name09" />
   <label>Email:</label> <input name="email09" id="email09" class="stored" placeholder="email09" type="email" /><br/>
   <label>Name :</label> <input name= "name10" id= "name10" class="stored" placeholder= "name10" />
   <label>Email:</label> <input name="email10" id="email10" class="stored" placeholder="email10" type="email" /><br/>
   <label>Name :</label> <input name= "name11" id= "name11" class="stored" placeholder= "name11" />
   <label>Email:</label> <input name="email11" id="email11" class="stored" placeholder="email11" type="email" /><br/>
   <label>Name :</label> <input name= "name12" id= "name12" class="stored" placeholder= "name12" />
   <label>Email:</label> <input name="email12" id="email12" class="stored" placeholder="email12" type="email" /><br/>
   <label>Name :</label> <input name= "name13" id= "name13" class="stored" placeholder= "name13" />
   <label>Email:</label> <input name="email13" id="email13" class="stored" placeholder="email13" type="email" /><br/>
   <label>Name :</label> <input name= "name14" id= "name14" class="stored" placeholder= "name14" />
   <label>Email:</label> <input name="email14" id="email14" class="stored" placeholder="email14" type="email" /><br/>
   <label>Name :</label> <input name= "name15" id= "name15" class="stored" placeholder= "name15" />
   <label>Email:</label> <input name="email15" id="email15" class="stored" placeholder="email15" type="email" /><br/>
   <label>Name :</label> <input name= "name16" id= "name16" class="stored" placeholder= "name16" />
   <label>Email:</label> <input name="email16" id="email16" class="stored" placeholder="email16" type="email" /><br/>
   <label>Name :</label> <input name= "name17" id= "name17" class="stored" placeholder= "name17" />
   <label>Email:</label> <input name="email17" id="email17" class="stored" placeholder="email17" type="email" /><br/>
   <label>Name :</label> <input name= "name18" id= "name18" class="stored" placeholder= "name18" />
   <label>Email:</label> <input name="email18" id="email18" class="stored" placeholder="email18" type="email" /><br/>
   <label>Name    :</label> <input name= "name19" id= "name19" class="stored" placeholder= "name19" />
   <label>Email:</label> <input name="email19" id="email19" class="stored" placeholder="email19" type="email" /><br/>

   <label>Message:</label>
   <textarea name="message" id="message" class="stored" placeholder="message"></textarea>

   <input type="submit" class="demo-button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

> How to play: Open the fiddle, input some text, then rerun it.  When it first load, the inputs are empty.  A second later they'll load what you entered before.

---

Your seems to have problem with storage's application, instead of a specific issue.

Above is a working fiddle.  Here is how it works:

1. The code has 40 input fields, each with unique id. 
    <sup>(use different id to distinguish same name fields on different forms)</sup>
2. On page load, run `load_all` which detect `localStorage` with try catch. 
    If ok, it calls `load_one` for each input fields, then hooks function `save` to their `input` events. 
    <sup>(try catch can detect cases where `Storage` exists but access denied, e.g. SO snippet.)</sup>
3. `load_one` will take the `id` of current input (`this`) as key, and load value from `localStorage`. 
    <sup>(The code here defaults to empty.  Better code should skip the setting if no value.)</sup>
4. When an input is changed, `save` will take the `id` of current input (`event.target`) as key, and either save its value (if non-empty) or remove its entry (if empty) from `localStorage`. 
    <sup>(Storage space is limited.  It's good habit to clean up.)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I personally think you have some errors in the head section of the page therefore the rest of the javascript (the section where you're storing your data in LocalStorage) doesn't run. As user1273587 pointed out, Have you looked into your developer console to see if there are any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few logical ambiguities that so can provide only possibilities:

1. localStorage.clear(); better to use .removeItem("...")
2. where is localStorage.setItem("") ? I can read $(.stored)

but how does

localStorage[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();

work for you?

Hope I can give a better answer if what I have mentioned are relevant for you to correct and respond.